# How do I create custom instance templates in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-completion

Intellij supports 'instance templates' i.e. templates usable with expression followed by a period, such as `cast`, `new` etc. So `MyClass.new` expands to `new MyClass(I)` where `I` is the cursor.

Now I want to create my own template, `expression.orElse` which expands to:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(expression).orElse(I)
```

I tried looking for options in Editor > Live Templates, but couldn't find anything relevant. Is this not possible in IntelliJ IDEA, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 'instance templates' are actually called [postfix completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#) templates in IDEA.

Starting with version 2019.2, custom postfix templates can also be created by going to Editor > General > Postfix Completion, as specified [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#reference.custom.postfix.templates) and detailed in [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2019/09/11/increase-productivity-with-custom-postfix-completion-templates/).

For the asked case, the values would be:

- Key: orElse
- Minimum language leve: 8
- Applicable expression types: non void
- Value:

  ```java
  Optional.ofNullable($EXPR$).orElse($END$)
  ```

Variables:

- `$EXPR$`: Replaced by the target expression
- `$END$`: Location of cursor after substitution

Enabling 'Apply to the topmost expression' disables the scope selection popup that appears on selecting the template.